# В чём ошибка при заполнении массива случайными данными Java?

Tags: java

```
public class massiv {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] myArray = new double[10];
        for (double i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            myArray[(int) i] = (double) Math.round((Math.random() * 30.5) - 15.5);
            System.out.println(myArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: вы предлагаете угадать, где у вас ошибка?

Comment: Здесь? `for (double i =`

Comment: @tym32167, тут банальная ошибка, видна не вооруженным глазом `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` и выглядит она следующим образом: `Index 10 out of bounds for length 10`, дело в условии цикла, нужно просто сделать: `for (double i = 0; i < 10; i++) {` и все заработает, так-как размер массива `[10]` и массив будет начинаться с 0 и до 9. а не до 10 - ибо это уже будет 11 элемент. А еще проще: `for (double i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {`

Comment: @And я хотел автора просто пофорсить номально оформить вопрос.

Comment: @tym32167, для каких целей, вопрос вполне нормальный и оформлен кодом, ошибку можно увидеть исполнив в любой песочнице или на локалке. По этому ваш флуд не уместен в принципе.

Comment: @And я писал свой комментарий до того, как вопрос был изменен. К тому же, вы измеряете качество вопроса какими то своими критериями, а я [пользуюсь справкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Ну и если не хотите флуда, не пишите ничего мне, и я вам не буду отвечать, и комментарии не запачкаем и вам будет радость от отсутсвия флуда.

Comment: @tym32167, изменен был лишь правкой кода, так-как оформлен был не по нормативам ресурса и некоторый код был текстом - это видно в [истории](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/999002/revisions): это значит, что ваш комментарий флуд, не нужно ссылаться на справку, вопрос оформлен нормально, а то, что вы пытаетесь крутиться и отмазываться не есть хорошо.

Comment: @And никаких кручений и отмазываний. Давайте я вам ясно прямо поясню что я хотел: я хотел, чтобы автор словами описал проблему, чтобы перед тем, как парсить код глазами, можно было бы прочитать, что автора беспокоит. Если вы с этим не согласны, то это ваше право и оно меня не касается. Мне вообще не ясно, какой вы результат от беседы этой ожидаете?

Comment: @tym32167, с вами бесполезно вести диалог, ибо прикрываетесь справкой, а сами ей не следуете, ибо новых участников не принято троллить за нормально оформленный вопрос. Текст тут не обязателен, если есть код и заголовок, что и следовало доказать. Откланяюсь.

Comment: @And Счастливо. Мне тоже нет никакого удовольствия выслушивать ваши необоснованные обвинения в мой адрес.

Answer (score 3):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Index 10 out of bounds for length 10` - Индекс `10` выходит за пределы длины `10` - это означает, что индекса `10` быть не может, так-как массивы начинаются с `0`.
Вы указали размер массива `[10]` - это значит, что `10` элементов, можно поместить в данный массив.
В данном случае индекс будет начинаться с `0` и заканчиваться `9`. что в итоге даст `10` элементов.

```
public class massiv {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] myArray = new double[10];
        for (double i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            myArray[(int) i] = (double) Math.round((Math.random() * 30.5) - 15.5);
            System.out.println(myArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А зачем так сложно?
Вы сами пишете тяжелый для понимания код, а потом не понимаете, почему возникает ошибка.
Сделайте так:

```
double [] myArray = new Random().doubles(10).map(i->i*35.5-15.5).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

В таком выражении ошибку допустить практически невозможно и читается элементарно.

Comment: Согласен, очень лаконичный и красивый код. Ну, думаю, автор пока новичок, по этому позволительны ошибки.